# Retrieving Manually Inputted Data Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Would it be possible to create documents in Firestore and then later reference it within swift/xcode/app? I want to manually add restaurant data into Firestore and then reference the data (city,type, phone number, etc.) within an app.

What do you recommend I do to be able to retrieve the manually typed out document entries?

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. Accessing it is no different than any other Firebase data.

Comment: I would suggest an alternative as adding data to Firebase via the console is going to be tedious. You should craft some code to upload said data to Firebase instead of manually entering it. As far as accessing the data, the getting started guide covers that - did you go through it yet? If no - that should be the first step.

Comment: That was very helpful thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible and not that hard to figure out when you look at the offical docs.

**SDK IOS SETUP**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

**Getting started with firestore**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#ios

**Creating a new document in the collection "USERS"**

```
// Add a new document with a generated ID
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
ref = db.collection("users").addDocument(data: [
    "first": "Ada",
    "last": "Lovelace",
    "born": 1815
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error adding document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
    }
}
```

**Reading that data**

```
db.collection("users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
        }
    }
}
```

For referencing documents made by users you could safe the UserID to the firestore document and filter the documents in the app by Current user ID.
This is mostly used in apps.

I would also suggest to watch some videos from:
https://peterfriese.dev/
This will give you a clear understanding on what to do with the data you get back.